# Undesired space between list elements

Tags: html, css

**The problem is over, I'm now going on with my website development, thanks.**

The problem is on my website (I'm viewing it in Chrome): http://albertorestifo.com/

Between the elements of the navigation menu, there is a undesired space between the border and the next list element. It is visible when you hover on "gallery".

Here the HTML:

```
<nav>
            <ul>
                <li class='active'><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about/">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact/">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

And here the CSS:

```
header nav, header nav ul, header nav ul li, header nav ul li a { height: 100%; } header nav ul li a { display: block; }

header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 150px;

  padding: 0 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
}
  header nav ul li:last-child { border-right: 1px solid #2d2d2d; }

  header nav ul li:hover, header nav ul li.active {
    background-color: #0072bc;
  }

  header nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
```

Plus a small reset:

```
ul, ul li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

I point out that I'm using Normalize.css, so every browser should display it.

I have no idea how to fix this, it never happened to me in the past!

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/EaAvx/

Comment: It's better to set the padding on the `a` element (you made it a block element anyway) so that when a user clicks in the padding, the link is followed. Now, the user would click on the padding of the list item, which will do nothing.

Comment: @BramVanroy Yeah, you are absolutely right, I will fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your `list-items` are `inline-block` elements.

Use any of the following solutions:

**Change HTML to this:**  removing the white space in your markup..

```
<li class='active'><a href="/">Home</a></li><li><a href="/gallery/">Gallery</a></li><li><a href="/about/">About Me</a></li><li><a href="/contact/">Contact Me</a></li>
```

**or..**

```
<li class='active'><a href="/">Home</a></li><!--
--><li><a href="/gallery/">Gallery</a></li><!--
--><li><a href="/about/">About Me</a></li><!--
--><li><a href="/contact/">Contact Me</a></li>
```

**As an alternative to removing the white space, you can always add a negative margin:**

```
header nav ul li {
    margin:0px -2px;
}
```

**or set the `font-size` to 0px on the parent..**

Note, there is still a 1px gap because of this in your CSS:

```
border-left: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
```

... if you wanted to, you could avoid all of these '*hacks*' and just change the element from `inline-block` to a floating element.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine, it do looks bad in the code, but that's not important. I was not aware of this characteristic of inline-block display. Thanks.

Comment: @Alberto I added an alternative.. there are more options here http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ EDIT.. it is technically not bad code to remove white space.. there are actually much worse solutions, such as not closing the tags, or using a negative margin..

Comment: Really an interesting article, actually, using flexbox may solve me a lot of issues, it will also be easier to make it responsive.

Comment: @Alberto or, changing the `inline-block` elements to floating elements

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have `li` as inline-block.

Set this:

```
nav > ul {
   font-size:0;
}

nav li {
   font-size:16px;
}
```

And done.

Comment: That way I would not be able to declare the font-size in ems, right?

Comment: Clever way of hacking inline-block. I'll have to remember this.

Comment: Yes, you have a disadvantage there.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all whitespaces, compress codes and that works pretty well. Even cross browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix that like this, here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/EZFkG/)

```
header nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 150px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use all selector to set padding and margin   then use box-sizing

```
*, *:after, *:before  {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EaAvx/2/